# Does Java have a function that lexicographically orders lists (not their elements)?

Tags: java, sorting, haskell

In Haskell, lists of type `Ord a => [a]` have a lexicographical ordering. For example,

```
> compare [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4]
LT
> compare [1] [1, 2]
LT
```

This is an immediate generalization of the lexicographical ordering most languages have on strings. In Java, for example,

```
"abc".compareTo("bcd")  // -1
"a".compareTo("ab")     // -1
```

Is there any Java function in the standard library or other library that implements the lexicographical ordering of lists that Haskell has? I would expect it have a type signature along the lines of

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(List<T>, List<T>)
```

Implementing it myself wouldn't be difficult, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Are you looking for a list implementation that keeps the lexicographical order of its elements, or do you want a function that compares two lists lexicographically?

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic One that compares two lists lexicographically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If third-party libraries are fair game, then in [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) this is just `Ordering.natural().lexicographical()`.  There isn't anything for this built into basic Java, though.

Comment: Note that as of Guava 21.0, you can simply use the new `com.google.common.collect.Comparators` class and just use `Comparators.lexicographical(Comparator.naturalOrder())`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such method that I know of. `List` (and its concrete implementations, such as `ArrayList`) do not extend/implement the `Comarable` interface, meaning that they implement no ordering themselves.

I think this is a correct language decision, because lists, in my opinion, indeed do not have a canonical ordering.

You can implement you own comparator which compares lists, and pass this to objects which need to compare list (for example `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`). For example:

```
class LexicographicalListComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<List<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<T> o1, List<T> o2) {
        Iterator<T> i1 = o1.iterator();
        Iterator<T> i2 = o2.iterator();
        int result;

        do {
            if (!i1.hasNext()) {
                if (!i2.hasNext()) return 0; else return -1;
            }
            if (!i2.hasNext()) {
                return 1;
            }

            result = i1.next().compareTo(i2.next());
        } while (result == 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just as Hoopje said, `List` does not implement the `Comparable` interface. If you want to implement your own comparator to lexicographically compare strings (and after that you could order lists of strings), Java has the [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class:

> The Collator class performs locale-sensitive String comparison.

If that's not enough you could use [RuleBasedCollator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html), it works as `Collator` but you can personalize it a lot more.

Both of them implement the `Comparable` interface so may use `compare`.

```
import java.text.Collator;
...
Collator c = Collator.getInstance();
c.compare(s1, s2);
```

If you want it to follow some locale-sensitive rules, you must do:

```
import java.util.Locale;
...
Collator c = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("es", "MX"));
c.compare(s1, s2);
```

Here is more info on [Locale](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html).

Comment: Lexicographical string ordering has nothing to do with comparing lists lexicographically.