# Most efficient code to compare lists

Tags: java, collections, java-8, comparison, java-stream

I have these classes:

```
Object 1
 String label
 List<Object2>

Object2
 String label
 List<Object3>

Object3
 String label
```

I want to compare two lists  of `Object1`.
This is what I did:

```
public class Object1 implements Comparator<Object1> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object1 o1, Object1 o2) {
     int compare = o1.getLabel().compareTo(o2.getLabel());
        if (compare == 0) {
            Iterator<Object2> iterator1 = o1.getObjects2().iterator();
            Iterator<Object2> iterator2 = o2.getObjects2().iterator();
            while (iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext() && compare == 0) {
                Object2 t1 = iterator1.next();
                Object2 t2 = iterator2.next();
                compare = t1.getLabel().compareTo(t2.getLabel());
            }
        }
        return compare;
}
```

And I did the same for `Object2`.
I sort my list of `Object1` by calling it in the code by:

```
SomeObject.getListOfObject1().stream().sorted();
```

Is there any other method "cleaner" than this? I feel like I am missing something...

Comment: "I sort my list of Object1 by calling it in the code by: `SomeObject.getListOfObject1().stream().sorted();`" that would only sort stream, not source of stream. You need to skip `.stream()` call and sort list directly.

Comment: Hi, First at all, your test can be wrong : if the two list hasn't the same size, your comparaison won't be full (it'll end at the smallest of the two lists)

Comment: It seems there should be a helper to lexicographically compare two lists, but apparently not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769122/does-java-have-a-function-that-lexicographically-orders-lists-not-their-element

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, I recommend you to sort the list directly using [Collections.sort(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)
2. Secondly, I'd implement the `compare(..)` method to all the `Object1`, `Object2` and `Object3` each. If you want to create in the future more complex structures using these object, they will be already implemented.
3. Lastly, implement the `equals()` and the `hashCode()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

one simple way you could go about it is to override the `equals()` and `hash()` method of your objects then use the `equals()` method of the list to compare two lists eg. `list1.equals(list2);`